# How to encrypt id in URL laravel

Tags: php, laravel, encryption

I want to encrypt the id in URL I'll show my controller code and route. I've already used `Crypt::encrypt($id);` in my controller but it's not working properly so I've commented that line in my controller

this is my controller

```
public function update(TenderRequest $request,$id){
    $tender = TenderMaster::findOrFail($id);
    //Crypt::encrypt($id);

    if($request->extend_date < $request->end_date || $request->bid_status > 0){                   
        return 'unsuccess';
    } else{ 
        $transaction = DB::transaction(function () use($request,$tender,$id) {
            $tender->extend_date = $request->extend_date;
            $tender->remarks = $request->remarks;
            $tender->update($request->all());
        });

        return 'BID '.$tender->ref_no.' Succesfully Updated';
    }
}
 
                         }
```

this is my route

```
  Route::post('tender/update/{id}','Tender\TenderMasterController@update')->name('bid.update');
```

this is my blade

```
<form action="{{route('bid.update' ,Crypt::encrypt('id'))}}" class="form-horizontal" id="bid-update" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    @method('POST')
    @include ('tender.form', ['formMode' => 'edit'])
</form>
```

Comment: do you want to elaborate more, what have you tried so far

Comment: i want to encrypt  my id in url eg: http://127.0.0.1:8000/tender/605/edit that 605 is my id and user can be change the id i want to stop that and i use Crypt::encrypt($id); but its not working

Comment: add that information to your question .... but it sounds like you would be better with something like 'hashids'

Comment: What do you mean by *its dose not working properly*? `Crypt::encrypt($id)` would the best option.

Comment: @SougataBose`Crypt::encrypt($id)` is not working **can** **you** **please** **tell** **me** how to use  `Crypt::encrypt($id)` in my code

Comment: Why not use uuids? or a hashid as @lagbox suggested. Maybe, use as a slug. And slug route model binding is coming to laravel in the next release, and you can even go as far as removing the find or fail when you use slug. (You can even now, by binding the slug, or any other for that matter, to desired model)

Comment: @user3532758 you don't even need to set any binding, you can set on the model what it should use for the route key  `getRouteKeyName()` and how it is resolved ... if you always wanted it to be resolved by slug when using Implicit Bindings that is, otherwise a binding is great

Comment: @lagbox `Crypt::encrypt($id)` is not working can you please tell me how to use `Crypt::encrypt($id)` in my code

Comment: well i wouldn't take this approach at all, but what "is not working" ... what does that mean "it isn't working"? in your `update` method you wouldn't be encrypting anything, you would be decrypting to get the actual id ....

Comment: @lagbox its not working that means the url is not encrypted

Comment: you are not generating any urls in the code you have ... the code you have here would not have anything to do with encrypting anything, the only thing it could be doing is decrypting ... the URLs that point to this route would have to have that parameter encrypted

Comment: @Vivekkalanka `Crypt::encrypt($id)` not ecrypting the `id`? What do you get when you decrypt it?

Comment: How are you setting the urls?

Comment: @SougataBose first i set the encrypt in route like this  `Route::post('tender/update/encrypt($id)` and after i decript it in my controller `$id = decrypt($id);` like this i dont know its correct way or not can you pleace tell me the correct way

Comment: anyone can help me to solve  this  please .. .!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use laravel builtin encryption to achieve this:

While adding your route in frontend, encrypt id with encryption helper like this:

```
{{route('bid.update', encrypt($id))}}
```

Now, In your controller, decrypt the id you have passed.

```
public function update($id, Request $request){

    $ID = decrypt($id);
    $tender = TenderMaster::findOrFail($ID);

    ..
    ...
}
```

I hope you understand.

Here is the docs:

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-encrypt

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-decrypt

Comment: this works perfectly, i used this when i only build with laravel. I'm currently building a web app with react and laravel.
Do you know how to encrypt id's before exposing the data through API endpoint?

Answer (score 5):

Put this in your form action tag

```
<form action="/tender/update/{{Crypt::encrypt('id')}}" class="form-horizontal" id="bid-update" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    @method('POST')
    @include ('tender.form', ['formMode' => 'edit'])
</form>
```

And replace this line of your controller:

```
$tender = TenderMaster::findOrFail($id);
```

With this:

```
$tender = TenderMaster::findOrFail(Crypt::decrypt($id));
```

And don't forget to add this line above in your controller

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;
```

Hopefully it'll work

Comment: can you please explain me to how to use this in my code ..cuz iam new to laravel

Comment: What you are using to send your id to the controller ? Ajax or form submit ? can you show your blade form code?

Comment: iam using form submit ..!

Comment: Okay then do this in your form action tag. <form action="tender/update/{{Crypt::encryptString('id')}}">

Comment: @Vivekkalanka Check my above answer. I've updated it.

Comment: why would they encrypt the string `'id'`

Comment: Okay @Vivekkalanka just replace the encryptString with encrypt and decryptString with decrypt

Comment: @KhalidKhan now generating a error play load is undefined

Comment: @Vivekkalanka I've updated my above answer but please make sure your @include(tender.form) should not be enclosed in form tag

Comment: @Vivekkalanka If you are facing any problem. mention here

Comment: @KhalidKhan brother that error is not fixed yet :,(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203226/discussion-between-vivek-kalanka-and-khalid-khan).

Answer (score 2):

there's function encrypt and decrypt

but, i would like to disagree with idea of encrypting user id, its far from best practice

i would like to recommend you to use policy, [policy guide](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authorization#writing-policies)

Comment: yeah i know but security reason i want to encrypt that id

Comment: @Vivekkalanka no you don't, policy is that security you're looking for, you don't protect it in url, you protect it via policy in your backend